# Delete STATEMENT with InnerJoin Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

I made this select statement to find duplicated rows I want to delete. I though that I simply change SELECT TO DELETE and It'd delete rows, but it didn't.

This is select statement:

```
select * FROM MYCARD T1
INNER JOIN( SELECT IDCARD, YEAR, MONEY FROM MYCARD GROUP BY IDCARD, YEAR, MONEY HAVING COUNT(IDCARD) > 1 ) T2 ON
T1.IDCARD = T2.IDCARD AND T1.YEAR=T2.YEAR
AND T1.MONEY = T2.MONEY
WHERE T1.IDMONEY = 5 AND IDCARD=80
AND ID not in (select min(ID)
from MYCARD
WHERE IDMONEY=5
AND IDCARD=80
group by IDCARD, YEAR);
```

and I wanted to use this delete:

```
DELETE FROM MYCARD T1
INNER JOIN( SELECT IDCARD, YEAR, MONEY FROM MYCARD GROUP BY IDCARD, YEAR, MONEY HAVING COUNT(IDCARD) > 1 ) T2 ON
T1.IDCARD = T2.IDCARD AND T1.YEAR=T2.YEAR
AND T1.MONEY = T2.MONEY
WHERE T1.IDMONEY = 5 AND IDCARD=80
AND ID not in (select min(ID)
from MYCARD
WHERE IDMONEY=5
AND IDCARD=80
group by IDCARD, YEAR);
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

I also tried this:

```
DELETE FROM MYCARD
WHERE EXISTS (select * FROM MYCARD T1
INNER JOIN( SELECT IDCARD, YEAR, MONEY FROM MYCARD GROUP BY IDCARD, YEAR, MONEY HAVING COUNT(IDCARD) > 1 ) T2 ON
T1.IDCARD = T2.IDCARD AND T1.YEAR=T2.YEAR
AND T1.MONEY = T2.MONEY
WHERE T1.IDMONEY = 5 AND IDCARD=80
AND ID not in (select min(ID)
from MYCARD
WHERE IDMONEY=5
AND IDCARD=80
group by IDCARD, YEAR))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work, because joins are not part of the [Firebird delete syntax](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-delete).

You need to use a delete with an exists, for example

```
delete from mycard t1
where exists (
   <a correlated subquery to identify the rows to delete>
)
```

or a similar way to identify the records to delete. Bottomline is: all logic necessary needs to be in the `where` clause.

Given the example, you need to do something like:

```
DELETE FROM MYCARD T1
WHERE T1.IDMONEY = 5 AND T1.IDCARD = 80
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT IDCARD, YEAR, MONEY 
    FROM MYCARD T2
    WHERE T2.IDCARD = T1.IDCARD 
    AND T2.YEAR = T1.YEAR
    AND T2.MONEY = T1.MONEY
    GROUP BY T2.IDCARD, T2.YEAR, T2.MONEY 
    HAVING COUNT(T2.IDCARD) > 1
)
AND T1.ID not in (
    select min(ID)
    from MYCARD
    WHERE IDMONEY = 5
    AND IDCARD = 80
    group by IDCARD, YEAR
)
```

You may need to add an additional `AND T2.IDMONEY = 5` in the select in the exists (unless `money` and `idmoney` are the same thing).

Comment: but when I put my select statement into where exists, it still doesn't work

Comment: @ktos1234 Please update your question with the statement you tried.

Comment: @ktos1234 that doesn't work because it is not a correlated subquery, so it will delete all your rows as long as the query has at least one row. I will update my answer when I can find the time.

Comment: Ok, I got this error when I tried your code:
Unsuccessful execution caused by system error that does not preclude successful execution of subsequent statements.
lock conflict on no wait transaction.
deadlock.
update conflicts with concurrent update.

Comment: You probably have a concurrent transaction modifying the same table while running this statement, or you did not rollback one of your previous attempts. You may need to execute this statement at a higher isolation level, or take your database offline so you are the only user when executing this.

Comment: I don't have any other transactions. When I try to delete single row, delete statement works fine. I am working on copied database, so I am only user.

Comment: @ktos1234 If the database was copied instead of backed up and restored, you may have a dangling transaction that has a record locked, although I can't exclude the possibility that this is some kind of bug in the Firebird version you are using.

Comment: Ok I tried again and It works. Thank you. Just one more question, is it any way to optimize this statement? I have more records and I takes a lot of time to complete statement.

Comment: @ktos1234 Adding an index on `(idcard, year, money)` might improve things. You could also consider creating a temporary table, populating it with what needs to be deleted, and then use a less complex statement to perform the actual delete.

Comment: Creating index helped a lot with first select query, but this thing still takes too much time : T1.ID not in( select id from temp_table).

Comment: @ktos1234 You could try to transform that to a `not exists`; or maybe you need an index on `(idmoney,idcard)` as well.

Comment: Can you help me convert it to not exists?